# Splitting an Existing Large Webpage into multiple pages

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, search-results

My website is 5 years old. Each page is big. The content of pages are cached by google and other search engines and showing in search results.

I want to split each large page into small pages for better readability and to make the page loading faster.

I have a doubt in this. Suppose I split a large page into multiple pages. Then, when user searches a content, search engine may still show that the content is  available in the large page, but the content might have been moved into one of the small pages.

Will this be a problem for SEO? How to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt this will give you any problems (if anything, it should be a net benefit as it will reduce bounce). If there are any issues with inbounds not seeing the content they expect, it won't be a problem for long.  Assuming you have pagination links set up properly and/or use sitemaps, Google will adjust its index in due course and begin directing users to the correct page.

If I were you, I would make sure the pagination navigation is easy to see and also consider allowing a single-page view as a navigation option.  That would give you the best of both worlds.